# What is this bar on my dashboard next to gas mileage?

Tags: mileage

See this

[image]

.

[image]

On the gas mileage indicator, it says 250 km.

Right to the left of it, there's an orange bar. There's actually two: the big one that indicates the amount of fuel left, and then there's a small orange one to the right of the big one. What does that indicate?

Comment: Make Year and model of car would be nice to know.

Comment: Wonder if you can find an owners manual online.

Answer (score 5):

Searching the number under the image leads me to believe this is "Royalty-free stock photo ID: 1465044698
Novosibirsk, Russia – July 09, 2019: Citroen C4, close-up of the dashboard, speedometer and tachometer with orange backlight. modern car interior"

Took a look through [a manual on manualslib](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/766219/Citroen-C4.html) but didn't see anything conclusive.

To be honest given that a similar bar seems to be present on the tacho in a region I would assert to be "high engine revs/warning/danger" I would presume this bar means "low fuel level when the gauge is in this zone". Being rendered thus also provides some symmetry to the layout and look of the tacho and fuel gauges. The only thing that I'm not totally convinced by is that this bar represents a 6th of the gauge and most other cars I've owned set aside more like an 8th of their gauge for the low fuel zone

Comment: Typically on US cars, there is a low fuel warning when estimated 50 miles left before you run out of fuel. And obviously that takes into effect observed fuel economy.   My guess that inner bar represents an equivalent (adjusted for recent fuel economy performance).  Does the inner bar get longer when you coast down a big mountain?

Comment: I think you'd have to do s lot of coasting to affect the average significantly, but you could be right - Citroen have always been into stuffing their cars full of electrickery/if it grows and shrinks then this could effectively be a "x miles remaining at current average consumption" indicator in reinforcement of the "250km to empty tank" readout in the dial  center. Would have thought the manual would make a point of it.. I didnt see anything but I might have missed it